# How to detect and use the page language in nextJS (ReferenceError: window is not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Im trying to make a site that could identify the country and set the language.

To do this in react i use to call thw window.navigator.language. The entire file:

```
import * as pt from "./pt";
import * as en from './en';

let translate;

if (window.navigator.language == 'pt-PT' || window.navigator.language == 'pt-BR') {
  translate = pt.default;
} else {
  translate = en.default;
}
export default translate
```

the pt / en files its just JSONS with all texts.

But window doesnt exist in nextJS

**That error appears: ReferenceError: window is not defined**

I need to use out of a react file.
Because i just import and use like this:
{Translate.header.label_opts_clients}

I will import and I use this in a XML (react) file and in a JSON file
like:

```
export const headerOptions = [
  {
    title: "`${Translate.header.label_opts_home}`",
...
```

How can i do this?
I know that exist useRouter(hook), so if you need to take the url in a page you can use.
I already had that problem, and i solved with this:

```
...

const { pathname } = useRouter()
  
  const [crumbs, setCrumbs] = useState<string[]>();

  useEffect(()=>{
    renderCrumbs()
  },[pathname])

  const setHref = (links:string[], index:number|string) => {
    let linkPath = ""
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {      
      linkPath = linkPath + "/" + links[i]      
    }

    return linkPath
  }

  const renderCrumbs = () => {
    let links = pathname.split('/').slice(1);
    let limit = links.length;
    let array = [];

...
```

But this just work in a function component.

I tried to put the condition in a function and return the let translate, and use the translate with parentheses ({Translate().header.something}) but didnt work.

I tried to use this too (but doesnt work):

```
if (window !== undefined) {
  // browser code
}
```

And i cant use hooks or components did/will mounth.

My code pictures:

[My folder organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4h73.png)

[The translates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS0cZ.png)

[The translate code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcRRk.png)

[How i will import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALD8J.png)

[The EN JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCyWH.png)

[My other JSON that i need to use the translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klp7t.png)

[trying to do a useEffect in my _app (laoult)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luNd7.png)

[Window verification in JS script and brought the JSON file to translate archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LayGS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found.
If you are using NextJS v10.0.0 you can use a new advanced feature.

**Internationalized Routing - i18n**

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

First of all you need to config your **next.config.js** and add the i18n module export.
If you already had some other plugins (like me) you will need to put them together.

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = withImages({
    esModule: false,
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT', 'es-ES'],
        defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
      },
});
```

With my project configured for the languages that i want, I went to my translation file and used a next hook - **useRouter from next/router**

```
import * as pt from "./pt";
import * as en from './en';
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export const traducao = () =>{
  let routes = useRouter();

  let translate;
 
    if (routes.locale == 'pt-PT' || routes.locale == 'pt-BR') {
      translate = pt.default;
    } else {
      translate = en.default;
    }
  
  return translate 
}
```

And the i just use in my project like a function:

**{traducao().homeText.button_text}**

Work well, recognizes the browser language and switche.
But unfortunaly you cant use in a Json, because you are using a hook, and hooks just works in a function component.

Comment: how did you deal with this issue: Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20616

Answer (score 1):

The window object can be referenced once the DOM is rendered. Usually, it is used in useEffect hook like so -

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window) // window is not undefined here
}, [])
```

in your case, from what I understand, you are trying to check the language and return the content from the pt file and further use it in another react component as header options.

Here's what might work,
Change your translate file to a function -

```
import * as pt from './pt'
import * as en from './en'

const translate = (window) => {
    const { language } = window.navigator
    
    if(language == 'pt-PT' || language == 'pt-BR') return pt.default
    else return en.default
}

export default translate
```

Now use it in your react file in a useEffect function -

```
import translate from 'YOUR_PATH_TO_TRANSLATE'

const SomeReactComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const translatedData = translate(window) // now window is defined

        let headerData = {
            title: translatedData.header.label_opts_home
            ... 
        }
        
        
    }, []) // componentDidMount in classes
}
```

Or, if you want to get the JSON header data from a separate file, you can create a separate file like so -

```
import translate from 'YOUR_PATH_TO_TRANSLATE'

const getHeaderData = (window) => {
    const translatedData = translate(window) // now window is defined

    let headerData = {
        title: translatedData.header.label_opts_home
        ... 
    }

    return headerData
}
```

and then, use it in your main component like so,

```
import getHeaderData from 'YOUR_PATH_TO_GETHEADERDATA'

const SomeReactComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        let headerData = getHeaderData(window)
    }, [])
}
```

I hope this works.

Comment: But, if i do this, i will need to add a useEffect in every single page?

Comment: Dont have a way that i can do this just one time?
Like, transforme my translate archive in a reac component.

Do a :
 **useEffect(() => {
    setup()
  }, [])

  const setup = () => {
    if (!window) return
   'CODE'
}**
Or something like that???

And then maybe i use in other pages with: **{translate().header.button_header_btn}**

Comment: I add some picures to make more easy to understand

Comment: In that case, you can use only one useEffect in your Layout component and you can conditionally render the children after you have your translate data, passing your translate data as props to the children. This way, you can use it in all of your pages as the translate data will be available to all the pages as props.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't worked. I did a useEffect in my _app (nextJS main file) and did a windows verification in my translate index file. (did with and without the else). But the problem persist. The same thing than before, worked for 10 minutes, but then the NEXTJS remember that it cant undersant the window.
i used the import like this: **{isLanguage.homeText.button_text}**

Comment: **Server error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'homeText' of undefined**
Because it cant understand isLanguage, isLanguage  use the traducao const that use the window

Comment: I see that you are not passing the window object as a parameter from your useEffect in your _app.tsx. The whole point of using the useEffect hook was because the window object is available in it.

Comment: I tried this to, but when i pass the Window as a parameter to my useEffect observer this appears: **ReferenceError: window is not defined**

Comment: Case the windows really is not defined, my application just will recognize the window when the component is mounted

Comment: Theres a way that i can use a dynamic import ? that file isnt a xml/react component, so i could use the dynamic import with a ssr: false ?

Comment: OBS: Im using Typerscript